# Can retrieve attributes of elements in a hash in Ruby, but not the elements themselves

Tags: ruby, performance, hash

I'm having huge problems with retrieving elements from the hash `node_hash` in the code below. The hash contains nodes of a phylogenetic tree, built from data available [here](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/taxonomy/taxdump.tar.gz). Each node has a unique ID, which is the key of the hash. When I try to access an element of the hash e.g., `node_hash[10]`, Ruby just spins its wheels and cannot retrieve it. However, if I do something like `node_hash[10].name` the name is returned. I know the proper relationships are being set up because I can do something like

```
node_hash[1].children.each do |child|
  puts child.name
end
```

And I get the expected output of

```
root
Viruses
Viroids
unclassified sequences
other sequences
cellular organisms
```

but then it just waits after printing all that. Here is the full code.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :name, :kind, :children, :parent
  def initialize(name=nil, kind=nil, children=nil, parent=nil)
    @name   = name
    @kind   = kind
    @parent = parent
    if children
      @children = children
    else
      @children = []
    end
  end
  def add_child(child)
    @children << child
  end
end

node_hash = {}

File.open("taxdump/names.dmp", "r") do |name_file|
  name_file.each_line do |line|
    split_line = line.split("|")
    if split_line[3].include? 'scientific name'
      id_num = Integer(split_line[0])
      name   = split_line[1].strip
      node_hash[id_num] = Node.new(name)
    end
  end
end

File.open("taxdump/nodes.dmp", "r") do |node_file|
  node_file.each_line do |line|
    split_line = line.split("|")
    id_num = Integer(split_line[0].strip)
    par_id = Integer(split_line[1].strip)]
    child  = node_hash[id_num]
    parent = node_hash[par_id]
    child.parent = parent
    child.kind   = split_line[2].strip
    parent.add_child(child)
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** So I just let one of the nodes load, and after about a minute, what looks like the entire structure of the tree was printed. It seems Ruby is recursively walking the tree (displaying the node's parent and its children, then the parent's parent and its children, etc. I'm going to try and override `inspect`. Hopefully that will work.

**EDIT 2:** That did the trick.

Comment: Show us sample of your data that you have trouble with.

Comment: Sorry? There is no sample of the data that I'm having trouble with. It all gets read into `node_hash` perfectly fine. The problem is retrieving elements from the hash. It just takes forever if I try to access an element of the hash, e.g., `a = node_hash[10]`.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `node_hash[1].children`. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just let one of the nodes load, and after about a minute, what looks like the entire structure of the tree was printed. Ruby recursively walked the tree (displaying the node's parent and its children, then the parent's parent and its children, etc. Generating the string was what was taking so long. Overriding `inspect` to change how each node is displayed fixed the problem.